# Import MySQL dump file to SQLite

Tags: java, android, mysql, sql, sqlite

Here is my use case:
I have an sql dump file provided by a server application that I don't have access to, neither to the MySQL database that originates the file.
The sql dump file is an ordinary one, common base SQL syntax, as those generated by phpmyadmin.
I download this text file into an Android device. The columns are just of type 'int' or 'text', not other types.
I want then to import this file into the Android app's SQLite database - basically reading the file into a stream, then executing one-by-one the sql statements.
My question: is there any existing class either in Android or available-of-your-knowledge that I can use in Java/Android and import the MySQL dump file straight into SQLite, so that to spare a couple of time to develop a parser myself?
Again, it's not about external tools.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have to do this import on a regular basis or is it a one time job?

Comment: Not a cron job. I just née a parser class for the sql dump file

Comment: I didn't mean cron job. Do you have to do this only once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because I faced this issue I think my findings and solution could be in the interest of others.
Here it is:

- MySQL is much richer in terms of data types than SQLite, so there is NO exhaustive transcoding implementation possible.
- for the common data types, what fits both as content representation are 'integer' and 'text'.
- the index key has a different syntax.
- overall, the MySQL dump file would require too much parsing for a small result.

THE SOLUTION however is very simple, even if we don't have access to the originating - MySQL - database, as following:

- load the MySQL dump in another transient MySQL-type database where you have full control.
- use a simple (PHP) script to read then write the content of the MySQL tables into a text file.
- read this text file with another script (Java, in my case, for Android) and feed the SQLite database tables. It is assumed that the SQLite schema has been previously created.

This is basic but, believe me, it is the most appropriate for such functionality.
MySQL and SQLite are definitely not alike as construction!

Answer (score 2):

Do you have shell access?  You could just `cat file.sql | sqlite3 my.db` although as @VMai mentions in the comments, this may not work due to MySQL-specific SQL dialect without preprocessing.

[Here is a good blog entry](https://web.archive.org/web/20160507233537/http://www.michenux.net/android-database-sqlite-creation-upgrade-245.html) of how to do it in code.  If you have the MySQL-specific dialect to worry about, you'd either have to preprocess or modify it in the stream of work in code.

You could use one of the tools listed [here](https://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ConverterTools) to do preprocessing on the SQL if it doesn't import well straight out of MySQL.

Comment: @woot You're an optimist. MySQL's SQL dialect will break such attempts easily. The problem is the parsing of MySQLs dump with removing of MySQL specials and a bit of translating.

Comment: Perhaps, but I'm assuming that any preprocessing can occur before the file is shipped to android and the question was more about how to execute the file.

Comment: @woot I cite from the last but one sentence _that I can use in Java/Android and import the MySQL dump file straight into SQLite_ I understand this exactly as a search of a class that can import MySQL dump files without preprocessing.

Comment: Well I'm not aware of any, but in the interest of progress I would look at that blog entry and add in any modifications to the stream of sql as needed.

Comment: @VMai I added your concerns specifically.

Comment: @woot: the blog link seems fine. Your answer is at least useful. I'll mark it as answer after doing the code if it is a match, for future interested. Thanks.

Comment: @GingerOpariti Wish I had a better answer for you, but I can't think of any other way.

Comment: @Sardathrion I changed it to the wayback archive link.

Comment: As an alternate to the wayback link, I found the code on GitHub: https://github.com/exabakr/android-app/tree/master/YourAppIdea/src/main/java/org/michenux/android/db

Comment: Actually the latest GitHub link is https://github.com/Michenux/YourAppIdea